# "Tall, Dark, and Handsome" Character Archetype?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I'm looking a singular word that implies the archetype of "tall dark and handsome". The origin of the word would also help-- I've seen a lot of responses, here and on Google, referencing "The Story of Hester Malpas," but that's not what I'm thinking of. I was once told there was a word that meant that, and it was derived from the first use of the character type, and now I'm totally blanking on it the night before an essay on a character that totally embodies that.

Comment: What, like a *hunk*? Can you clarify what type of word you're looking for by adding an example sentence?

Comment: I don't think there is any definitive "first use" of the stereotype. It was a fortune telling cliché long before romantic literature was a thing ("you will meet a tall, dark stranger", etc.). Some of the precursors of today's stereotypical romantic hero might be the Byronic Hero, Austen's Mr. Darcy, and Heathcliff from Wuthering Heights...

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TallDarkAndHandsome

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of Adonis? Don't think this is the archetype for tall, dark and handsome, but there is some conceptual overlap.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Byronic Hero', while not a singular word, is definitely the right kind of area. Examples include:

- Heathcliff: "A half-civilized ferocity lurked yet in the depressed brows and eyes full of black fire, but it was subdued; and his manner was even dignified: quite divested of roughness, though stern for grace..." (*Wuthering Heights*, Emily Bronte, Ch. 10)
- Satan: "Satan, with vast and haughty strides advanced,
  Came towering, armed in adamant and gold..." (*Paradise Lost*, John Milton, Book VI)

If that's not quite right, a one-word phrase that might be helpful for you is "antihero". There's a definition here (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anti-hero), for starters.